# Do away with/Hide Emulator Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, android-emulator

I learnt from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) the various keyboard commands for an emulator. I therefore thought one could afford to do away with/hide the on-screen keyboard that has the DPad buttons, the home, menu and back buttons; and have the emulator occupy less screen space. For emulators that are not snapshot-enabled, one can do this!

However for snapshot-enabled emulators, I find that whatever hardware config I set it's not happening. By me, the hardware configs that matter are:

1. Keyboard Support

   Hardware back and home buttons

For each of the above you either don't add them to the config, or add them and set value 'yes' or add them and set value 'no'. So far none of the configs I tried so far worked. By my tries, at least, it is found that no matter what I do with regard to the Keyboard Support configuration or Hardware Back/home buttons (independently of each other) - yes, no or don't add - the keyboard remains there. I didn't find a hot-key to hide the keyboard either.

I thought therefore that it's better to post a question on this here, than try booting with umpteen different hardware configurations (it'll be a precious 2-3 minutes spent on each configuration trial!)

Thanks in advance,

P.S. I use Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013856/eclipse-android-avd-emulator-does-not-display-buttons-for-custom-resolution-skin) (in the question, not the answer) that if one sets a custom resolution in pixels rather than selecting from the built-in ones, then the emulator does **not** display the skin with the emulator controls.

Below is the configuration I therefore set to solve my problem, at the same time not creating new problems:

[image: The Appropriate Settings]

I just estimated the dimensions in pixels of a WQVGA size instrument and set that as my custom resolution.